# validates helper methods with modelless session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a `session controller` which manages login/logout actions.These are not associated with any model. I want to use the `validates` helper methods with this session controller so that I can use, `:maximum, :minimum`, etc. conditions for the `username and password`. But if there is no model, how do I use these validation methods. Also, if I use these helpers it is easy to integrate with my `simple_form` login page for the `error message`, similar to which I have done for my `user` registration page.

If above helper methods are not possible to be used, what alternative I have which is easy to interface with my simple_form?

Answer (score 1):

Validations can be used without creating a model, i.e. a class inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`. You can have a class that includes `ActiveModel::Validations` and use its methods. For example:

```
class Session
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :username, :password

  def initialize(user, pass)
    @username = user
    @password = pass
  end

  validates_length_of :username, minimum: 5
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 7
end
```

And you use like that:

```
session = Session.new("name", "secret")
session.valid? ## => false
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but simple_form is not showing the errors.